# Sometimes tabs.getSelected callback doesn't run

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've written a Google Chrome extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fhmcfamnddgoloojehbeokifhaiiebfm), and I'm noticing that the extension works on my Linux desktop, but not my Linux laptop (both running the Chromium 13.0.782.107~r94237-1 in Debian unstable)

It seems that the callback I'm passing to `chrome.tabs.getSelected` doesn't run on my laptop, except when I have this popup page open in the debugger. (But it works perfectly on my desktop) Any idea what's going on?

Here's the code in question:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">

function goTo(url){
  if (url.search("://") == -1 &&
    url.search("@") != -1 &&
    url.search("mailto:") == -1 ) url = "mailto:"+url;
  else if (url.search("://") == -1 ) url = "http://" + url;
  url = url.replace(/\s/g,"");
  console.log(url);

  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab){
    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id,{"url":url});
  });
  window.close();
}

function pasteHandler(e) {
  var t = e.target.type;
  if (t == "textarea" || t == "text" || t == "password"
      || e.target.isContentEditable) {
    return;
  } 
  var url = e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain").replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
  goTo(url)
}

function textBoxEnterPressed(e){
   if(e.keyCode == 13){
      goTo(document.getElementById('edit').value);
      return false;
   }
   return true;
}
</script>
   </head>
   <body onpaste="pasteHandler(event)">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="float:left">
     <tr><td>
        Paste in the text box to edit the URL first,
        or paste outside the box to go straight there.
     </td></tr>
     <tr><td>
        <input type="text" name="edit" id="edit" size="100"
        onkeypress="return textBoxEnterPressed(event)"/>
     </td></tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are closing window before callback finishes running. Try:

```
function goTo(url){
    ...
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab){
        chrome.tabs.update(tab.id,{"url":url});
        window.close();
    });
}
```

Comment: That fixed it. I guess there was a race condition between the callback and the window.close, and my desktop and the debugger had better timing.